# Read Usernames and Passwords from a txt file

Tags: c++, readline, fstream

I need to pull usernames and passwords from a .txt file and I am having a difficult time wrapping my mind around how exactly to do this. I'll try to break this down.

1. Open the file
2. Read in the Usernames
3. Compare a username against a user input
4. Compare a password against a user input associated with the username
5. return true or false if the username and passwords match

Yes, this is homework. And I am learning how to use the fstream while waiting for USPS to ship my class txt book. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
bool User::check(const string &uname, const string &pass)
{
    //open the file

    fstream line;
    line.open("users.txt");

    //Loop through usernames
        //If a username matches, check if the password matches
}
```

The users.txt file looks like this:

```
ali87   8422

ricq7   bjk1903

messi   buneyinnessi

mike    ini99ou

jenny   Y00L11A09

end
```

Comment: Mike, I would like to ask you what you think the "high level" goal of this project is? It looks like it's a little more then just understanding fstream...am I correct? (Teachers really like to pull that, putting "extra learning" in every assignment, who do they think they are!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/136-basic-file-io/

Answer (score 2):

I think the following pseudo-algorithm may be a better option for you:

1. Input username, password
2. Open file stream to file
3. Search stream for username match (exit if non found)
4. If found, compare **encrypted** input password against stored **encrypted** password.
5. If found, return success, else, "No username found or password incorrect.".

For step 3, you would store each line buffer in a string, which you could store in a container of strings.
Ideally, during this processing, you might split the string into a username, password pair, and then store them in a std::map; and then access this via map.find(input username) == input password.

You shouldn't need to store the map for more than the duration of the login process, you should then discard the map (maybe as a local function variable).

If your program actually has a purpose, this is ideal, otherwise, just get it working :).

Comment: I don't know for sure but if the person's learning fstream, I am going to assume that they're pretty new to either programming, or this language, BUT I will say that the first thing I thought of when I read the question was that it was much like a hash table. I like your answer, although it might be more advanced then the Mike knows how to do, but it would be good practice. I upvoted ya!

Answer (score 2):

I included `iostream`, `fstream` and `cstring`. And using `namespace std`.

```
int main()
{
char login_password[20];
char stored_password[20];   
char login_username[20];
char stored_username[20];

fstream pull("users.txt",ios::in);
if (!pull) { 
    cout<<"File not loaded!"<<endl;
    return -1; 
}
cout<<"Username: ";
cin>>login_username;
while(strcmp(login_username,stored_username)){ 

//if login and stored usernames are equal, function strcmp returns 0,
//at first loop they are certainly not, so it is: while(1)

    pull>>stored_username;
    if(pull.eof()){   //if it is the end of file
        cout<<"Username does not exist. "<<endl;
        return -1;  
    }
}
pull>>stored_password; 

//since username and password are in the same line, password next to
//correctly inputted username is saved in stored_password

cout<<"Password: ";   
//now user enters password to confirm username
cin>>login_password;
while(strcmp(stored_password,login_password)){
    cout<<"Wrong password. "<<endl;
    cout<<"Try again: ";
    cin>>login_password;
}
cout<<"Login successful."<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

`users.txt` looks like this:

- Lena84 uzumymw
- Doris20 kjkszpj

there is one white space between username and password.(also without bullets)